# How to implement role based login using SAML

Tags: security, spring-security, wso2, saml, saml-2.0

I have integrated SAML with spring boot and it is working as expected. But I wanted to implement login based on region and role, using which the user can select and login and access the selective content. And user can able to switch the account profile i,e role and region at any point of time. So, when the user logs in saml token will be generated with the attributes and can we refresh or enrich the token with the selected role & region attribute or is there any suggestion which will help in implementing this?

Comment: Why do you want to generate a new SAML token? AFAIU this seems something you need to handle in the UI. Whatever the roles assigned to that particular user will be returned once the login flow is completed and based on the returned user roles you can generate the UI. IS samples available here can help you. https://github.com/wso2/samples-is

Comment: Once the user logs in he can select assigned roles and based on his role selection ui will get change